# Dealing with "ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed" (Electron 7.0)

Tags: javascript, electron

Having upgraded to Electron 7.0, I've noticed this deprecation message:

```
(node:8308) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
```

The code in question is:

```
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    electron.protocol.registerBufferProtocol(MY_PROTOCOL,
      (request, callback) => {
        const uri = request.url;
        if (uri) {
          callback({ mimeType: 'text/plain', data: Buffer.from(uri) });
        }
        else {
          callback({ error: -324 }); // EMPTY_RESPONSE
        }
      },
      error => error? reject(error): resolve()
    );
  });
```

What's the proper way of calling `registerBufferProtocol` now, as of Electron 7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It took me some noticeable time to figure out how to call `registerBufferProtocol` properly with Electron 7.0, so sharing this with the community and my future self.

According to Electron's [Breaking changes](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/7-0-x/docs/api/breaking-changes-ns.md) document, `registerBufferProtocol` is now synchronous, so calling it has actually got simpler:

```
  electron.protocol.registerBufferProtocol(MY_PROTOCOL,
    (request, callback) => {
      const uri = request.url;
      if (uri) {
        callback({ mimeType: 'text/plain', data: Buffer.from(uri) });
      }
      else {
        callback({ error: -324 }); // EMPTY_RESPONSE
      }
    });
```

The confusing (to me) part of the warning was that the `callback` is actually **not** the `callback` arg to the `handler`, but rather is the last `completion` arg passed to the [`protocol.registerBufferProtocol`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol#protocolregisterbufferprotocolscheme-handler-completion) API itself.

Comment: And so, how do you handle the not registered error ?

Comment: I found the answer myself: A search in electron repository for 'protocol' leads me to the file "spec-main/api-protocol-spec.ts" line 16 look like the API is not returning a Promise.
So we could write: `protocol.registerBufferProtocol("...", () => ... ).then( (??)=>, err=> )`

Comment: To be clear: the error is saying that the *third argument to `registerBufferProtocol()`* is no longer needed. I.e. the `error => error? reject(error): resolve()` can be removed from OP's code.